# Joining the maximum of a column from another table

Tags: postgresql

I created the following tables:

```
create table items (
    id serial primary key,
    store_id int,
);

create table bids (
    item_id int,
    amount int
);
```

I want to select all items from a certain store and include information about the highest bid:

```
select items.*, max(bids.amount) from items
    join bids on bids.item_id = items.id
where items.store_id = $store_id
```

I get the following error:

> column "items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your Postgres version?

Comment: Postgres version is irrelevant isn't it? He is using an aggregate function without providing a GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Trent In later versions of Postgres you can mention only the primary key of the table in `GROUP BY` instead of all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted a window function?

```
select items.*, 
       max(bids.amount) over (partition by bids.item_id) as max_bid_for_item
from items
    join bids on bids.item_id = items.id
where items.store_id = $store_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message tells you what you're doing wrong.  To use an aggregate function (`max()`), everything else in your `SELECT` clause must be in a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT items.*, MAX(bids.amount)
FROM items
JOIN bids ON bids.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.store_id = $store_id
GROUP BY items.id,items.store_id;
```

Comment: How about if I want the `MAX(bids.amount)` to be 0 for a row if no bids exist for that item? Right now if there are no bids the item just doesn't get selected.

Comment: That's a separate question, but you can do that with `COALESCE`: `SELECT items.*, COALESCE(MAX(bids.amount),0) FROM items...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
JOIN bids b ON b.item_id = i.id
WHERE i.store_id = $store_id
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM bids nx                 -- No bid should exist
   WHERE nx.item_id = b.item_id -- ... for the same item
   AND nx.amount > b.amount     -- ... but with a higher price
   );
```